# No route matches [GET] "/users/country.html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

It is nice when I directly open 'http://localhost:3000/country.html' or click 'Country' button on navigation bar. But if I click 'Login'/'Signup'(http://localhost:3000/users/signin.html) first and then click 'Country' button, the url link to 'http://localhost:3000/users/country.html'. It shows 'No Route matches [GET] "/users/maison.html"'. Even more, the colour of 'Login' changes to a strange red which is similar to the default red '404' page in public. 
Could anybody tell me why different clicking sequences will lead to different urls and how can I figure out the issue? Thanks!

This is an app based on Ruby on Rail, with devise, ruby-2.3.7,'rails', '~> 5.2.2' and mysql. I am using macOS Mojave.

```
'''
    'application.html.erb':

<div class="outside_container">
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="navbar clearfix">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav left">
          <li><a href="./introduction.html">Introduction</a></li>
          <li><a href="./country.html">Country</a></li>
          <li><a href="./maison.html">Maison</a></li>
        </ul>


          <% if notice %>
            <p class="notification"><%= notice %></p>
          <% end %>
          <% if alert %>
            <p class="notification"><%= alert %></p>
          <% end %>


      <ul>
          <p class="nav right">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path %> | 
              <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %> |

            <% else %>
              <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> |
              <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %> |

            <% end %>
          </p>
        </ul>

    </div>  
  </div>
'''
```

sorry for missing route.rb, here it is:
    'route.rb':

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users


#make sure devise/session/new, which means the login page is the root page
  devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'country#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end

get '/country', to: 'country#index'
get '/maison', to: 'maison#index'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"

  #root 'page#welcome'

  resources :country
  resources :maison
  resources :introduction
  resources :dashboard

end
```

Comment: Never use `href` in Rails, always use `link_to`, otherwise the links are not generated correctly.

Comment: I've never seen a RAILS route with .html, could you try removing it? SO use /country instead of /country.html. Otherwise, please also share contents of your routes.rb.

Comment: `maison` is not nested under users so the preceding dot (in the link) is most likely the issue that dot means from the current location (relative) so example.com with a relative "./maison.html" means example.com/maison.html but if the url is example.com/users then the relative "./maison.html" means example.com/users/maison.html

Comment: I prefer you to read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the dot from your URLs. The dot makes it a relative path, so wherever you are in your app, it will use that path as the starting point for those links. If you remove the period, it will always use your root path to build the links.

```
<li><a href="/introduction.html">Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="/country.html">Country</a></li>
<li><a href="/maison.html">Maison</a></li>
```

Comment: Much better to use `link_to`

Comment: thanks for reminding of using link_to! It is a good point. I am gonna to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have an href `<li><a href="./maison.html">Maison</a></li>` that is pointing to `/maison` which means somewhere in your routes.rb there needs to be a route defined that matches that, as well as a controller that the route interfaces with:

```
get '/maison', to: 'home#index`
```

In the above route, we're saying "any `get` request to the `/maison` address should trigger the `index` method in the `home_controller` file in Rails.

Once you set the route and controller correctly, this should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

## There are a couple things:

1. The file should be titled routes.rb (plural)
   So change `route.rb` to `routes.rb`.
2. Use the command `$rails routes` or `$rake routes`
   To get a list of all routes you currently have available to you. If nothing shows, then rails is not recognizing your routes.
3. Use "Link To" for example
   `<%= link_to user.title, users_path(user) %>`